# Set checkboxes on/off based on plain text numbers

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a number of checkboxes, set up like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436365629" value="3349" data-value="3349">
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436382959" value="60" data-value="60">
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436382959" value="2013" data-value="2013">
```

I also have a simple text string of numbers separated by spaces in the page content:

```
<span id="boat-access-id">3349 60</span>
```

I want to set the checkboxes who's values appear in the text string to checked. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Where is the text string coming from?

Comment: Good point, updated question for clarity.

Comment: Actually I was thinking more of what generates the list. Is it (and/or the checkboxes) output from PHP? If so it is almost certainly easier to handle it in that code (and you should add the relevant parts to the question). If there's no PHP involved you should remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each function `$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index,item)` for loop checkbox and `.prop('checked', true)` to checked checkbox

```
function check(){
var idstring = $('#boat-access-id').text();
var ids = idstring.split(' ');
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index,item){
   //alert($(item).val());
   if(ids.indexOf($(item).val()) >= 0){
    $(item).prop('checked', true);
   }
})
}
```

```js
function check(){
var idstring = $('#boat-access-id').text();
var ids = idstring.split(' ');
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index,item){
   //alert($(item).val());
   if(ids.indexOf($(item).val()) >= 0){
 $(item).prop('checked', true);
   }
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436365629" value="3349" data-value="3349">
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436382959" value="60" data-value="60">
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436382959" value="2013" data-value="2013">

<p>List id to check:</p>
<span id="boat-access-id">3349 60</span>

<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `text()` of the span. `trim()` and `split()` the text to convert to array. Use `forEach()` to loop thru the array. Check if the check with the value exist, if it does, check it using `prop()`

```js
$("button").click(function() {

  $("#boat-access-id").text().trim().split(' ').forEach(function(o) {
    var cb = $('input[type="checkbox"][value="' + o + '"]');
    if (cb.length) cb.prop('checked', true);
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436365629" value="3349" data-value="3349">
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436382959" value="60" data-value="60">
<input type="checkbox" id="form-436382959" value="2013" data-value="2013">

<br />
<span id="boat-access-id">3349 60</span>
<button>Check</button>
```